# How to keep image's tintColor for an UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, tintcolor

I created a custom class `CircularButton` in which I can set a custom `image`, `backgroundColor`, `tintColor` for the image and `inset` to the edge of the button.

It's working fine, except for the `tintColor`. I want to be able to set the tintColor, but if I don't provide one, it should keep the original tintColor of my image (rendered as template image).

```
open class CircularButton: UIButton {

    public init(width: CGFloat, backgroundColor: UIColor? = nil, tintColor: UIColor? = nil, image: UIImage? = nil, contentMode: ContentMode? = nil, insets: UIEdgeInsets? = nil) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)

        self.backgroundColor = backgroundColor ?? .clear
        self.tintColor = tintColor ?? // issue is here
        self.imageEdgeInsets = insets ?? .zero
        self.imageView?.contentMode = contentMode ?? .scaleAspectFit

        setImage(image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)

        if width != 0 {
            widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
        }

        heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor).isActive = true
        clipsToBounds = true
    }

    override open func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        layer.cornerRadius = frame.width / 2
    }

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }
}
```

Here is how I initialize it :

```
let likeButton = CircularButton(width: 45, backgroundColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5), tintColor: .white, image: UIImage(named: "heart"), insets: .init(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5))
```

This is working, except that if I don't want to provide a tintColor, it takes the default blue tintColor for the button and render my image in blue.

Here is what I have tried in my custom class:

...

```
self.tintColor = tintColor ?? imageView?.tintColor
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `.alwaysTemplate` as `RenderingMode` wrongly here, this property is used to change the color of the image changing the original color for the tint Color in your component, you should use `.alwaysOriginal` if you want to keep the original color of the image in this component

to fix this use `.alwaysOriginal` instead of `.alwaysTemplate` in this line

```
setImage(image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
```

Comment: I wanted to be able to sometimes change the color of my image or keep the original color. Having the choice in my initializer.

Comment: @Funnycuni you can pass your image with the desired rendering mode and avoid to set that property inside your button, i can provide an example if you want to